# How to tackle this integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x} \ln \frac{1}{x} dx\quad (p>-1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

For improper integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x} \ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d} x\qquad(p>-1),$$ we observe that there is a term $\frac{\ln(1)-\ln(x)}{1-x}$ in which we can use Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$, then we can use $B$ function, but I'm stuck, I don't know how to simplify the result, the final result of this integral is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left ( n+p \right )^{2}}.$$ I don't know how to get to this point, could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: @Lorago it is dx

Comment: Make the substitution $x=\exp(-t)$ and refer to [$(25.11.25)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E25).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}}{1-x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=&-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}}{1-x}\ln\left(x\right)dx\\
=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x\\=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1-x} x^{p-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}$$
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$$
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}}{1-x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n x^{p-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+p-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+p}\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+p)^2}\\
=&\psi^{(1)}(p+1)
\end{align}$$

Where $\psi^{(1)}(z)$ is the polygamma function